# UIView.layer.presentationLayer returns final value (rather than current value)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation, calayer

Here's some relevant code inside a **UIView subclass**:

```
- (void) doMyCoolAnimation {
  CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
  anim.duration = 4;
  [self.layer setValue:@200 forKeyPath:anim.keyPath];
  [self.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
}

- (CGFloat) currentX {
  CALayer* presLayer = self.layer.presentationLayer;
  return presLayer.position.x;
}
```

When I use `[self currentX]` while the animation is running, I get `200` (the end value) rather than a value **between** `0` (the start value) and `200`. And yes, the animation is visible to the user, so I'm really confused here.

Here's the code where I call `doMyCoolAnimation:`, as well as `currentX` after 1 second.

```
[self doMyCoolAnimation];

CGFloat delay = 1; // 1 second delay
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  NSLog(@"%f", [self currentX]);
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you invoke the getter fairly immediately after the animation has been added to the layer, you should be getting values close to 0.4.  Try wrapping your get in a `dispatch_after()`

Comment: @CodaFi I am aware of this and was already using `dispatch_after()`. I'm checking at a valid time, but `presentationLayer` is pretending it is a model layer (the source of my confusion).

Comment: Isolate the KVC setter from the animation, then isolate the animation from the KVC setter to see what I mean.  In its current form the animation will do nothing, and the KVC setter will cause the layer to spring to its next position at the default implicit animation speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My UIView's layer's presentationLayer was not giving me the current values. It was instead giving me the end values of my animation.

To fix this, all I had to do was add...

```
anim.fromValue = [self.layer valueForKeyPath:@"position.x"];
```

...to my `doMyCoolAnimation` method **BEFORE** I set the end value with:

```
[self.layer setValue:@200 forKeyPath:@"position.x"];
```

So in the end, `doMyCoolAnimation` looks like this:

```
- (void) doMyCoolAnimation {
  CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
  anim.duration = 4;
  anim.fromValue = [self.layer valueForKeyPath:anim.keyPath];
  [self.layer setValue:@200 forKeyPath:anim.keyPath];
  [self.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where the idea for using KVC setters in animation code came from, but that's what the animation itself is for.  You're basically telling the layer tree to immediately update to the new position with this line:

```
[self.layer setValue:@200 forKeyPath:anim.keyPath];
```

Then wondering why the layer tree won't animate to that position with an animation that has no starting or ending values.  There's nothing to animate!  Set the animation's `toValue` and `fromValue` as appropriate and ditch the setter.  Or, if you wish to use an implicit animation, keep the setter, but ditch the animation and set its duration by altering the layer's `speed`.

Comment: The animation **can** be seen happening. Or are you claiming that the presentationLayer will be fixed if I used CABasicAnimation's `toValue` rather than [**implicit animation**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW3)?

Comment: Implicit animation with an explicit animation... This makes no sense.  CALayer will try its best to animate all property changes, but when you try and commit an animation that does nothing to a layer, it's going to do nothing.  What I'm saying is that `setValue:forKeyPath:` is not a step in creating an explicit animation like you seem to be trying to do.

Comment: [This guy does what I'm doing](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/11/prevent-caanimation-snap-back/). And it has worked for me up until I wanted to access the presentationLayer.

Comment: From the looks of your code, though, you're not following his example at all.  Nowhere in that blog post does it mention going through the KVC setter.

Comment: Alright, I figured it out. Adding a `fromValue` to the `CABasicAnimation` made the `presentationLayer` return the correct values! Thanks for your help @CodaFi.

Comment: There now, that's how an explicit animation works!  Sorry for all the trouble I managed to stir up in the lead-up to this.  I should not be on a site expecting clarity and expertise at 2 AM :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are creating your animation is wrong, as CodaFi says.

Either use an explicit animation, using a CABasicAnimation, or use implicit animation by changing the layer's properties directly and NOT using a CAAnimation object. Don't mix the two.

When you create a CABasicAnimation object, you use setFromValue and/or setToValue on the animation. Then the animation object takes care of animating the property in the presentation layer.